# Using Serilog to Application Insights - requests logging but not traces

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

**UPDATE**

By shutting down the application using *ctrl + c* in the console, the "finally" block of *program.cs* is executed, logs are flushed and saved to Application Insights. However, if the application is stopped abruptly, (browser window closed for example) logs are not sent to Application Insights and the information is lost, which isn't ideal.
Does anyone have method or suggestion to make logs flush more frequently or how to safeguard in the event of the application terminating unexpectedly

**ORIGINAL**

I'm trying to configure C# web application project to log files to Application Insights using Serilog. I have followed the documentation to configure the logger to read for the appsetting.json file and have been able to implement other sinks to write logs to the console, file SEQ etc, but the Application Insights won't work. Request data is available on application insights using the configuration below

Program.cs

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateBootstrapLogger();

Log.Information("Application Starting up");


try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

   builder.Host.UseSerilog();

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios,   see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapRazorPages();

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "the application failed to start correctly");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "connectionString": "MyConnectionString"
    
  },

  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "*MyConnectionString",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
        }
      }
      , 
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogcontext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ]

  }
}
```

Requests are being saved to application insights, but I can't get the logs (traces) or exceptions to be saved. Am I missing something??

*Edit*
I have log events written in the index like so

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    _logger.LogCritical("Serilog: Testing log critical");  
                    throw new Exception("Serilog iLogger Exception");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("Serilog: The value of i is {LoopCountValue}", i);
                    _logger.LogWarning("Serilog: Testing log warning");
                    
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "exception in the index Get call");
        }
    }
}
```

*Adding .csproj file*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> <PropertyGroup
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.AppSettings" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="5.2.2" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Could you please share the document which you have followed?

Comment: What is the `.NET Framework` you are using? Please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: .csproj file added. Have been following the serilog documentation on application insights https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights mainly

Comment: have also tired removing the "ApplicationInsights": {"connectionString": "MyConnectionString" }, section and also tried moving the connection string entirely to the environmental variables in launchsettings,json file

Comment: I have resolved this issue by shutting down the application from console window using *ctrl + c* rather than the "stop debugging" button in visual studio or closing the browser. Don't know why this works but the traces are sent to application insights when using this method